# ??? вместо кириллицы в SQL

Tags: python, sql, odbc

Использую библиотеку `pyodbc` код вставки выглядит таким образом

```
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO dbo.Sites (Sites,Links,Name)VALUES (%s,%s,%s)"""%(sitename,rhref,rtext))
    cursor.commit()
```

все идет без ошибок, однако в БД значение rtext попадает как `????` . Как исправить? Если это важно база данных лежит на сервере `AWS`

Comment: Добрый день. Проверьте везде кодировку, она должна быть одинаковая. Кодировка файла, кодировка базы, кодировка таблицы, кодировка поля в таблице, при соединении с базой тоже кодировка должна совпадать.

Comment: Пытаюсь сделать БД в `Utf-8` таким запросом  ALTER DATABASE Fortry CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci  выдает ошибку Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CONVERT'

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так
Для смены кодировки базы

```
ALTER DATABASE `имя базы` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Для смены кодировки таблицы

```
ALTER TABLE `tablename` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
//or
ALTER TABLE `tablename` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```